# Is there any erlang web framework which provides the same functionalities as in Dropwizard framework?

Tags: java, erlang, dropwizard, chicagoboss

Is there any erlang web framework which provides the same functionalities as in Dropwizard framework? I am not good in erlang and I want to make a website transition from java to erlang.

Comment: I'd recommend first getting good at erlang/OTP, before trying out frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

[Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/)'s appmod provides everything ***I*** need for building web apps. It's beautiful, it's fast, and it's pure Erlang (from a user's point of view). This might sound subjective:) But I think you should give it a try.

Yaws is very well documented and full of examples. There is also a book called *[Building Web Applications with Erlang: Working with REST and Web Sockets on Yaws](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449309968)* which can get you started very quickly.